# SQLite causes endless loop if I call function with useEffect

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and React-native. Basically my program is working like this, on one screen I can add an item to the table. Different parts of this data is retrieved and displayed on different pages. (all of the tutorials that I watched did everything on a single page)
On each display page I have the following code:

```js
        const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
                name: "booksdb",
                location: "default"
                
            },
            ()=>{
                
                console.log("db connected")
                
            },
            error=>console.log("db error", error)
            )
```

This code seems to work, however, when I try to have the data be retrieved automatically with useEffect, it causes an infinite loop.  “db connected” gets logged endlessly.
So my question first is this, is it normal to have the above mentioned code on every page where data will be accessed, or is there another way of doing things that does not cause an infinite loop?

I have tried using:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getInfo();
        console.log(tableLength) 
      }, [tableLength]);
```

This solves the infinite loop problem, but it doesn’t solve all of my problems. The idea is that the most up-to date data is displayed, therefore the function should be run whenever the table length changes (when the user adds an item) but now it only runs once, when the app loads.
My second question is this:  How can I have the getInfo function called whenever the table length changes?